# What is the name of the profession that makes mattresses?

Tags: word-request

A mattress maker is called what? I'm looking for an older description, the oldest the better. Is there a name for this profession?

Comment: There are dedicated words in other languages (Italian [***materassaio***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/materassaio), French [***matelassier***,...)](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/french-english/matelassier) - but not in English, I think. And ***if*** we didn't like [***mattress-maker***](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Pg5JvdqDq1MC&q=%22mattress+maker%22&dq=%22mattress+maker%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH3NOLgPLdAhVKjqQKHelUDow4ChDoAQg5MAM) (which appears as such in the UK 1931 "Census of Occupations"), we'd presumably have borrowed one of those foreign terms anyway.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by old. Early ones were made of straw, feathers, wool, etc. But before mattress making became a thing, I would imagine that bed makers provided the mattresses such as they were.

Answer (score 2):

No special word.  *"Mattress maker" or "Mattress manufacturer"* would be most easily understood.

Modern mattresses are made in factories by industrial processes. In the past and in craft contexts, adding cloth and cushioning to furniture is called upholstery, and is the job of the *upholsterer*, but they would be more concerned with adding cushions to seats than with making mattresses.

In the mediæval period, a mattress for all but the very richest would be a hemp sack (called a *tick*, but that meaning is not obselete), stuffed with straw, not requiring a skilled manufacture. - [source](http://www.oldandinteresting.com/medieval-renaissance-beds.aspx)

Comment: That's right. Mattress maker, candle maker, etc.